# Compute $\int_{\Gamma} \frac{\cos(z)} {z^2(z-3)}\, dz$ along the contour indicated in Fig

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

Here is the problem. How do I choose the correct denominator?

Compute
$$
\int_{\Gamma} \frac{\cos(z)} {z^2(z-3)}\, dz
$$
along the contour indicated in Fig below.

[image: Figure for question above]

Here is my answer.
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{\Gamma} \frac{\cos(z)}{z^2(z-3)}\,dz
&= \int_{\Gamma}\frac{\frac{\cos(z)}{(z-3)}} {z^2} \\
&= \frac{2\pi}{1!} f'(0)
\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
f(z) &=\frac{\cos(z)} {z-3}\\
f'(z) &=\frac{-\sin(z) (z-3) - \cos(z)}{(z-3)^2}
\end{align}
$$

$$
\frac{2\pi}{1!} f'(0) = \frac{-2 \pi i}{9}
$$

However, the answer given by Chegg wrote like this below.
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{\Gamma} \frac{\cos(z)}{z^2(z-3)}\,dz
&= \int_{\Gamma}\frac{\frac{\cos(z)}{z^2}} {z-3}\\
&= \frac{2\pi i}{0!} f(3)
\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
f(z) &=\frac{\cos(z)} {z^2}\\
f(3) &=\frac{\cos(3)}{9}
\end{align}
$$

Since 3 lies outside $\Gamma$, $\frac{\cos(z)}{z^2(z-3)}$ is not analytical on $\Gamma$. $\int_{\Gamma} \frac{\cos(z)}{z^2(z-3)}\,dz = 0$

Which one is correct?

Comment: The pole at $z = 3$ is irrelevant since it's outside the contour. That said I think your writing here is a bit all over the place, take a second look and make sure you have the right expression at each step

Comment: From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeros_and_poles): "A pole of $f$ is a zero of $1/f$" Also note that you are interested only in the poles that are inside the contour of integration. So that means in this case is that you are interested in the pole at $0$.

Comment: @StephenDonovan but  0 is inside contour. I have corrected my writing style. Plz have a look now.

Comment: @Andrei So you are suggesting my answer is correct instead of Chegg?

Comment: Indeed. Your $f(z)$ does not have singularity inside the contour, so all you need to compute is the residue of $f(z)/z^2$ at $z=0$.

Comment: @kile What I meant is that the Chegg solution is incorrect because the pole at $3$ is irrelevant: I agree with your solution since your $f$ is differentiable everywhere inside the contour